# what skill you need to know in order to make multiplayer website game?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I want to make a multiplayer game like "slither.io" or any io games but I am lacking the knowledge and the resource. So far I know that you need a server which its going to run on, some javascript knowlege, and the data which stores the information of the player. However, I honestly dont know where to start I want the game to have animation and responsive. I just want the information in order to make my idea into reality.

Comment: Some HTML5 and JavaScript tutorials seem like a good start.

Comment: Look into WebSockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've referred several people to Khan academy (a free resource) with great success.  A great interactive course for learning front end development basics.  If I were you, this is what I would start with.

[HTML and CSS](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css)
[Intro to JavaScript](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css-js)

They have more courses on jQuery and Javascript too that you should go through.

After that, you'll want to learn a server-side language like PHP or Node.js.  And to make a realtime multiplayer game you will need to use something like websockets.  Make sure to put into practice what you learn along the way, as programming is a skill.